# Restoring Emacs desktops with daemon + clients

Tags: desktop, emacs-daemon

How to use Emacs desktop functionality with emacs daemon + emacsclient instances?

I've enabled `(desktop-save-mode 1)` in my init file, and when I start the daemon I see messages like this:

```
Desktop: 1 frame, 2 buffers restored.
```

However, it does not restart any of emacsclient instances I have. When I start an `emacsclient` instance it's blank.

Is there a way to restore the desktop manually once I open a new emacsclient instance? Or is there a way to make this work another way?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have unremoved [desktop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) lockfiles, which will usually be in your config dir/folder, which is hopefully `~/.emacs.d/`. Here's a procedure for testing my hypothesis from a commandline (e.g. a Bash shell running in a terminal app under Linux):

1. Ensure you have no `emacs*` processes running: i.e., there should be null response to

   ```
   pgrep -l emacs
   ```

   If you *do* get a response, like

   ```
   $ pgrep -l emacs
   29422 emacs
   ```

   you will need to manually close your Emacsen, or brutally kill them with (e.g.)

   ```
   pkill -9 emacs
   ```
2. Check for desktop lockfiles in your config dir with, e.g.,

   ```
   find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
   ```

If there is null response to the 2nd commandline `&&` my hypothesis is correct, you should be able to start Emacs and see your desktop (i.e., all those buffers will be auto-open'ed). Note the preferred way to start both a fresh daemon *and* client is either

```
# create a GUI frame
emacsclient --alternate-editor '' --create-frame &
```

or

```
# start a TUI Emacs in current terminal
emacsclient --alternate-editor '' --tty
```

If there is **not** a null response to the 2nd commandline--i.e., you get something like

```
$ find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
/home/you/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

in your shell, then delete those lockfiles, e.g.

```
find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*' | xargs rm
```

Then rerun

```
find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
```

until you get a null response, then retest my hypothesis. (I.e., start a fresh Emacs--if you see your desktop buffers, I'm correct, else I'm not.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I ended up abandoning the whole desktops thing. I'll mark as answer.